# How to use col_types using readr's read_delim_chunked?

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I am trying to read a file in chunks and specify the `col_types`, see MWE

```r
write.csv(cars, "cars.csv")


library(readr)
readr::read_delim_chunked("cars.csv", function(x, i) {
  x
}, delim= ",", col_types = cols(
  speed = col_character()
), chunk_size = 10)
```

but I get erroneous output

```
NULL
```

but the non-chunked version works fine

```r
library(readr)
readr::read_delim("cars.csv", delim= ",", col_types = cols(
  speed = col_character()
))
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error: the code still runs, right?

Comment: @camille no. it's an erroneous output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be that when we do the `write.csv`, the row.names were included as a new column

```
write.csv(cars, "cars.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Also, we need `col_character()` instead of `col_character`

```
readr::read_delim_chunked("cars.csv",  DataFrameCallback$new(function(x, i) {
  x
}), col_types = cols(
  speed = col_character()
), delim= ",",  chunk_size = 10)
```

Comment: I think the issue is `DataFrameCallback$new`

Comment: Sorry the () is a typo

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you need to wrap the function in `DataFrameCallback$new` for reasons that I don't understand.

```r
write.csv(cars, "cars.csv")
```

Works

```r
readr::read_delim_chunked("cars.csv",  DataFrameCallback$new(function(x, i) {
  x
}), col_types = cols(
  speed = col_character()
), delim= ",",  chunk_size = 10)
```

Gives error

```r
readr::read_delim_chunked("cars.csv",  function(x, i) {
  x
}, col_types = cols(
  speed = col_character()
), delim= ",",  chunk_size = 10)
```